# New line TSX textscript issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tsx

I am trying to create paragraphs and new lines so my text doesn't look so cluttered.

I am new to Typescript and I can't seem to get the text to separate my paragraph. Here is what my text looks like

[image]

Here is my code:

```
export const aboutData: About = {
  profileImageSrc: profilepic,
  description: `Hello! thanks for taking the time to visit my professional website. My name is Jeremiah Dunphy (He/Him) and I work in a Strategic Senior Human Resources at CW Resources Inc. I have always been passionate about helping people and organizations reach their full potential, and I have found a perfect outlet for this passion in the field of HR and People Management.\n" +
               "\n" +
               "I began my career in HR almost a decade ago and have since gained a wide range of experience in various industries and organizations. I have held HR positions in both small and large companies, giving me a well-rounded understanding of the unique challenges and opportunities that different types of organizations face when it comes to managing and developing their human capital.\n" +
               "\n" +
               "I hold a Bachelors in Human Resources and a Masters in Business Administration. I am currently obtaining my doctorate in Human Resources and Business Management.In my current role as HR Director, I am responsible for overseeing all aspects of human resources management in over 20 states.\n" +
               "\n" +
               "Outside of work, I enjoy spending time with my Family, Coding, Data, Running, Website and Game Development. I am also an active member of the Society for Human Resource Management and am always looking for ways to stay up-to-date on the latest HR trends and best practices.\n" +
               "\n" +
               "As a Combat Veteran who has served on two tours of duty, I know firsthand the sacrifices that our military members make to protect our country. That is why I am committed to giving back to the veteran community through my volunteer work at the VA. Whether it is providing support and companionship to Veterans during hospital stays, helping with paperwork and benefits, or just being a listening ear, I am dedicated to doing whatever I can to assist and support our Veterans. It is my way of honoring their service and sacrifices, and I am grateful for the opportunity to give back to those who have given so much for our country.\n" +
               "\n" +
               "While Volunteering, I have had the opportunity to assist Veterans with a variety of tasks and needs. Whether it is providing support and companionship during hospital stays, helping with paperwork and benefits, or just being a listening ear, I am committed to doing whatever I can to help our Veterans.\n" +
               "\n" +
               "I am grateful for the opportunity to give back to those who have given so much for our country, and I am committed to continuing to support and assist Veterans in any way I can. It is a small way to show my appreciation and gratitude for their service and sacrifice."\n" +
  
               "Thank you for taking the time to learn more about me. I am excited to bring my skills and experience to bear in helping organizations and individuals reach their full potential."`
               
               aboutItems: [
                 {label: 'Location', text: 'Hartford, CT', Icon: MapIcon},
                 {label: 'Age', text: '27', Icon: CalendarIcon},
                 {label: 'Nationality', text: '', Icon: FlagIcon},
                 {label: 'Interests', text: 'People, Computer Science, Law and Psycology', Icon: SparklesIcon},
                 {label: 'Studying', text: 'Docotorate in Human Resources and Business Management - Capella University', Icon: AcademicCapIcon},
                 {label: 'Employment', text: 'Cw Resources Inc.', Icon: OfficeBuildingIcon},
               ],
             };
```

I have tried

/n

\n

/n

creating concatenate's

it renders it either as a string or it just does nothing and it is not visable.

any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent all day on this one task and I'd like to move on to the next section.

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap`

Comment: If this is html, then `\n` won't work. You need `<br/>`